# Can you get the UserAgent used by WebView in iOS without starting a WebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, user-agent

Is it possible to find out what User Agent (and other headers, such as Accept) that a WebView would use without having to first start a WebView.

I need to pass the User Agent and Accept headers to a service to check if a browser based connection is required or not. If the browser based connection is required, then I will start a WebView to the appropriate URL, the problem is if that request does not match the User Agent and Accept details that were used when checking if the browser was needed, then the request could fail.

I don't want to have to start a WebView unless a browser connection is actually needed by the service. If one is not needed then the App can continue directly to the next stage. I need to keep the UI as clean as possible, so don't want a WebView to appear just to get the header details.

I've seen some answers on getting this by using JavaScript from within a WebView, but I don't want the WebView to start just to get this. Is there any other way to find out what these headers will be in advance of starting the WebView?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get HTTP headers with an NSURLRequest.

[Check the documentation on NSURLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy)